# subset dataframe in to multiple using a dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, subset

I need to subset a dataframe in to three, based on the *start* of the column names, which are stored in a dictionary.

here is a df:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,5,size=(5, 10)), columns=('a_group1_sub','a_group1_actual','b_group1_sub','b_group1_actual','b_group2_total','b_group2_sub','b_group2_expected','class_first','class_second','area_x'))
```

and here is a dictionary where I want to separate the dataframe based on the following groupings: df1 = a_group1, df2 b_group2 and b_group2, df3 = class and area

```
groups = dict({1: ['a_group1'], 2: ['b_group1', 'b_group2'], 3: ['class', 'area']})
```

here is a loop i have tried

```
for k, v in groupings.items():
    print(df.loc[:,df.columns.str.startswith([v])])
```

it works if i do something like this, but not in a loop

```
df.loc[:,df.columns.str.startswith('a_group1')])
```

any comments are welcome, thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is that what you are trying to do?

```
df_list = list() # The output list of dataframes
for k, v in groups.items(): # for v in groups.values() if you don't use k
    # Get the columns that start with any of the elements in v
    cols = [c for c in df.columns if c.startswith(tuple(v))]
    # Subset df, df[cols], and append to the list of dataframes
    df_list.append(df[cols])

# df_list[i] contains the dataframe i
```

Comment: Thanks! Thats nearly what I want..but its not saving the output to new dataframes. Ideally I would like to store the new dataframes in a dictionary of three so they are accessible via e.g. df[0], df[1], df[2]

which i just did adding in   

  x = df[cols] /

  out.append([x])

Comment: How and where you store each resulting dataframe is up to you. I edited the answer and added one option. Theoretically you could also use a dict.